# Saving database row ids in a txt file to save query time? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem where user has many friends (users) and quite frequently I have to gather user-A friends 2 levels deep and store them in array to manipulate with them later. I am using a middle association table (friendships).

I made a guess that this would create huge issues when the database grows (in terms of query time).

That's why I wanted to know if it's more efficient to store users network (friends 2-levels deep) data in a txt file and read it whenever I have to get a person's network. This way I would cut down on sending tons of queries every time I need a persons network.

If it is indeed more efficient then can someone please give me a small example given my database structure (user->has many friends(Class User) through Friendships).

I hope my problem is clear.

The end result is that I want to gather a person's network of friends in an array (and later get this array from reading a file to skip database query)

Comment: Caching layer?   This is a perfect use case for something like memcache/redis/etc.  and there are tons of examples of your exact problem (social graph)

Comment: "I made a guess that this would create huge issues when the database grows (in terms of query time)." Why? Databases are fast, if you don't make a slow query and/or datamodel. You don't need a ton of queries to get this result, you need a smart query. Could you show us your datamodel?

Comment: if you are really concerned with database time,
you may want to use raw sql at some places as it bypasses the rails default validation and other middlewares to boost up the performance. https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

Comment: *"I made a guess . . ."* When it comes to database design, software design, and programming, guesses don't scale well. Generating 50 million rows of random(ish) sample data for testing is pretty simple.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that experienced with rails and SQL, maybe my question is a bit off... How does caching work in database exactly? Queries themselves would be fast (because they're simple) it's the amount of queries that bothers me.

Comment: I just populated the database with half a million records but the search seems to be working instantly (the social graph) is that reliable info (I tried it on a local machine)?